# How to check if values of column 1 in dataframe B are between the values of column 1 and 2 in dataframe A. If true, return column 2 of dataframe A

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, localization

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A has five columns: start_time, end_time, ID_user, ID_position and orientation. Dataframe B has four columns: timestamp, ID_user, ID_sender and RSSI.

I want to add the ID_position column of dataframe A to dataframe B, so I know which RSSI value (dataframe B) corresponds to which ID_position (dataframe A). To do this, I need to know where someone was on which time. So I need to check between which start_time and which end_time (dataframe A) the timestamp lies (dataframe B). In total, there are 277 positions.

In simple words: if timestamp (dataframe B) is between start time and end time (dataframe A), return ID_position to corresponding timestamp and add this as a column to dataframe B.

I have searched on many websites and tried many things, but this is probably the best I have come up with:
I changed the columns to tolist() because lists are proceeded faster than columns. I tried to use for-loops in a function to go through start time and timestamp and to compare them. Instead of using start time and end time, I tried to use only start because this resulted in less for-loops (but using end time is better). I tried merge, assign and so on but could not figure it out. The most promising solutions I have are placed below. The first solution resulted in a list of ID_positions for one timestamp, so not one position.

```py
def position (timestamp):
    pos_list = []
    pos = survey.ID_position
    time = 1540648136288
    for t in range(len(timestamp)):
        if (timestamp[t] <= time):
            pos_list.append(pos)
        elif (timestamp[t] > time):
            time = time + 8000
            pos = survey.ID_position + 1
    return(pos_list)


def numbers2 (position):
    pos_ID = []
    post_list = []
    for i in range(len(position)):
        pos_ID.append(position[i])
    def num_pos2(timestamp):
        pos_list = []
        pos = ID
        time = 1540648127883
        for t in range(len(timestamp)):
            if (time <= timestamp[t] <= (time+8000)):
                pos_list.append(pos[i])
            if timestamp[t] > time:
                pos_list.append(pos[i+1])
                time = time + 8000
                position = pos[i+1]
    return(pos_list)
```

Dataframe A (first few lines, 1108 rows × 5 columns, 277 positions in total)

```
    start_time      end_time        ID_user ID_position orientation
0   1540648127883   1540648129883   1        1           1
1   1540648129884   1540648131883   1        1           2
2   1540648131884   1540648133883   1        1           3
3   1540648133884   1540648136288   1        1           4
4   1540648179559   1540648181559   1        2           1
5   1540648181560   1540648183559   1        2           2
6   1540648183560   1540648185559   1        2           3
7   1540648185560   1540648187846   1        2           4
8   1540648192618   1540648194618   1        3           1
9   1540648194619   1540648196618   1        3           2
10  1540648196619   1540648198618   1        3           3
11  1540648198619   1540648201336   1        3           4
```

Dataframe B (first few lines, 209393 rows × 4 columns)

```
timestamp       ID_user ID_sender   RSSI
0   1540648127974   1   1080       -95
1   1540648128037   1   1          -51
2   1540648128076   1   1080       -95
3   1540648128162   1   1          -53
4   1540648128177   1   1080       -95
```

Expected outcome dataframe B:

```
timestamp       ID_user ID_sender   RSSI   ID_position
0   1540648127974   1   1080       -95     1
1   1540648128037   1   1          -51     1
2   1540648128076   1   1080       -95     1
3   1540648128162   1   1          -53     1
4   1540648128177   1   1080       -95     1
.......................... < a lot of rows between >
1809    1540648179571   1   1080    -75    2
1810    1540648179579   1   1       -55    2 
1811    1540648179592   1   1070    -96    2
1812    1540648179627   1   1069    -100   2
1813    1540648179669   1   1080    -78    2
1814    1540648179772   1   1080    -79    2
```

The total dataset can be found on: http://wnlab.isti.cnr.it/localization

I want to check between which start time and end time (dataframe A) the timestamps from dataframe B are, and I want to return the ID_position of dataframe A. So that in the end, dataframe B has a column with the ID_positions corresponding to the right timestamps. For example: if the start time is 1 and the end time is 4, and the ID_position is 1. I want to get ID_position 1 for timestamp 3 because that is between 1 and 4.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you also add an expected output of the small dataframes you added?

Comment: @Efran I added the expected outcome of dataframe B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an [`outer merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with both dataframes on `ID_user` which gives you a `many-to-many` product back (so these are all the combination eg. cartesian product).

Then we filter with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) on `start_time < timestamp < end_time`:

```
df = pd.merge(dfB, dfA, on='ID_user', how='outer')\
       .query('start_time < timestamp < end_time')\
       .drop(['start_time', 'end_time', 'orientation'], axis=1)\
       .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
print(df)
       timestamp  ID_user  ID_sender  RSSI  ID_position
0  1540648127974        1       1080   -95            1
1  1540648128037        1          1   -51            1
2  1540648128076        1       1080   -95            1
3  1540648128162        1          1   -53            1
4  1540648128177        1       1080   -95            1
```

**note** I didn't use inclusion with the `<` operator. You can change that to `<=` if needed.

**note2** If your dataframes are big. This will be memory consuming, see explanation about `many-to-many` above.

## Edit after OP's comment about multiple positions

I still get the right results.

```
# Print the new used dataframes
print(dfA, '\n')
print(dfB, '\n')

       start_time       end_time  ID_user  ID_position  orientation
0   1540648127883  1540648129883        1            1            1
1   1540648129884  1540648131883        1            1            2
2   1540648131884  1540648133883        1            1            3
3   1540648133884  1540648136288        1            1            4
4   1540648179559  1540648181559        1            2            1
5   1540648181560  1540648183559        1            2            2
6   1540648183560  1540648185559        1            2            3
7   1540648185560  1540648187846        1            2            4
8   1540648192618  1540648194618        1            3            1
9   1540648194619  1540648196618        1            3            2
10  1540648196619  1540648198618        1            3            3
11  1540648198619  1540648201336        1            3            4 

        timestamp  ID_user  ID_sender  RSSI
0   1540648127974        1       1080   -95
1   1540648128037        1          1   -51
2   1540648128076        1       1080   -95
3   1540648128162        1          1   -53
4   1540648128177        1       1080   -95
5   1540648179571        1       1080   -75
6   1540648179579        1          1   -55
7   1540648179592        1       1070   -96
8   1540648179627        1       1069  -100
9   1540648179669        1       1080   -78
10  1540648179772        1       1080   -79 

df = pd.merge(dfB, dfA, on='ID_user', how='outer')\
       .query('start_time < timestamp < end_time')\
       .drop(['start_time', 'end_time', 'orientation'], axis=1)\
       .reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
        timestamp  ID_user  ID_sender  RSSI  ID_position
0   1540648127974        1       1080   -95            1
1   1540648128037        1          1   -51            1
2   1540648128076        1       1080   -95            1
3   1540648128162        1          1   -53            1
4   1540648128177        1       1080   -95            1
5   1540648179571        1       1080   -75            2
6   1540648179579        1          1   -55            2
7   1540648179592        1       1070   -96            2
8   1540648179627        1       1069  -100            2
9   1540648179669        1       1080   -78            2
10  1540648179772        1       1080   -79            2
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Unfortunately, there are 277 positions and the code stops when every timestamp for position 1 has been found. The dataset is quite big, so I certainly have to run this in smaller pieces.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe edit your example data so it will catch this problem @user11410373

Comment: In total, there are 277 positions. Dataframe B is way bigger than dataframe A, so a lot of RSSI-values will be attributed to one position. I updated the expected outcome and as you can see, at row 1809 begins position 2. I am sorry that I was unclear in the beginning. @Erfan

Comment: I still get the right results when running this with your new dataframes @user11410373 . See my edited answer. Last dataframe is same as your expected result

Comment: thank you very much! It seems to be working after restarting Python @Erfan